# Resultado de operación da NaN

Tags: javascript

me sale "El promedio es: NaN" con este código. He hecho mil veces este ejercicio.. pero ahora mi mente se ha secado y no encuentro el problema. Sé que debe ser algo sencillo, pero aun asi. Ayudenme. Estoy medio cansado en estos dias.

```js
/* Realizar una pequeña calculadora que permita calcular el promedio entre las notas de 10 alumnos.
*/
var promedio = 0;
var nota = 0;
var suma;
var total = 1;
        
promedioAlumnos();

function promedioAlumnos() {
   do {
      nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nota nro "+total));
      suma += nota ;
      total++
      if (total>=10) {
         promedio = suma/total;
         alert("El promedio es: "+promedio) ;
      } 
   } while (total<=10)
         
}
```

Comment: ¿Y el valor inicial de _suma_?

Comment: Gracias, era eso. De todas formas lo he modificado tantas veces.. recuerdo haberlo inicializado en 0.. y haber tenido problemas igual. Pero si, era eso. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Me recomendas el mejor sitio para aprender JavaScript en profundidad? El llamado Vainilla.

Comment: El mejor sitio para aprender javascript puro es la documentación :)

Comment: ¿Que es la documentacion? ¿Es de libro o algo asi? Necesito interiorisarme mas.

Comment: Se refiere a leer  de [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no habías definido el valor de la suma, además el if estaba mal planteado por que daba la salida antes de terminar. El valor de la varibale total tiene que ser 0, ya que si no, el promedio de las 10 notas sale dividido entre 11, no entre 10.
Te dejo el código por aquí.

```js
           var promedio = 0;
            var nota = 0;
            var suma = 0;
            var total = 0;
    
    promedioAlumnos();
    function promedioAlumnos() {
    do  {
        nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nota nro "+total));
        suma += nota ;
        total++
        if (total>10) {
            promedio = suma/total;
        alert("El promedio es: "+promedio) ;
      } 
    
    } while (total<=10)
    }
```

Comment: Así como lo planteas, se están registrando 11 calificaciones, no 10.

Comment: Sí, gracias a todos. Yo lo he resuelto asi:

       var promedio;
        var nota = 0;
        var suma=0;
        var total = 1;

promedioAlumnos();
function promedioAlumnos() {
do  {
    nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nota nro "+total));
    suma += nota ;
    total++
    if (total==11) {
        promedio = suma/(total-1);
        parseInt(promedio);
    alert("El promedio es: "+promedio) ;
  } 

} while (total<=10)
 
}

Answer (score 1):

> Ademas de errores en variables el If no es necesario

```js
 var total=0
    var suma=0
   var total =0
    promedioAlumnos();
        function promedioAlumnos() {
        do  {
            nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nota nro "+total));
        
            suma += nota ;
            total++
            console.log('suma:',suma,'total:',total)
        // por ejemplo ingresa 3 notas
        } while (total<3)
         
                promedio = suma/total;
                console.log(promedio)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que **inicializar la variable suma**, que será obviamente al valor 0.
Si no, la instrucción suma += nota no se va a comportar como esperas, no va a sumar números.

Otra cosa, tu programa sólo te pide 9 números, no 10, para pedir 10 le he cambiado el total >= 10 por total > 10, y le quito 1 al dividir para calcular el promedio, si no dividiría entre 11.

```
var promedio = 0;
var nota = 0;
var suma = 0;
var total = 1;
        
promedioAlumnos();

function promedioAlumnos() {
   do {
      nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nota nro "+total));
      suma += nota;
      total++
      if (total > 10) {
         promedio = suma / (total - 1);
         alert("El promedio es: "+promedio) ;
      } 
   } while (total<=10)        
}
```

Pero mejor sería sacar el if (total > 10) del bucle, y simplemente pintar el promedio al salir del mismo:

```
var promedio = 0;
var nota = 0;
var suma = 0;
var total = 1;
        
promedioAlumnos();

function promedioAlumnos() {
   do {
      nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nota nro "+total));
      suma += nota;
      total++ 
   } while (total<=10);

   promedio = suma/total;
   alert("El promedio es: " + promedio);        
}
```